# Interference between \includeonlyframes and \onslide across tabular row

Tags: tables, beamer, errors, overlays

I seem to have run into a strange interference between `\includeonlyframes` and use of `\onslide` to uncover a row in a `tabular` environment.  Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \includeonlyframes{second}

  \begin{frame}{First frame}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
      \onslide<+->{Some & text}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[label=second]{Second frame}
    Some text on second frame
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex` on this example, I get "Missing `}` inserted."  Curiously, if I make any **one** of the following changes, then the example compiles successfully.

- Remove the `\includeonlyframes` line.
- Remove the `\onslide<+->{` and `}` from around the `tabular` row.
- Remove the `tabular` environment (and `&`), but leave `\onslide<+->{` and `}`.
- Replace `\onslide<+->{` and `}` with the switch form `\onslide<+->`.
  That is, use `\onslide<+-> Some & text`.
- Replace `\onslide<+->{` and `}` with `\uncover<+->{` and `}`.
  (It seems particularly strange that `\uncover<+->{` works but `\onslide<+->{` does not, especially considering the apparent equivalence discussed in [Differences and best practices: \onslide vs. \uncover, \onslide+ vs. \visible, \onslide* vs. \only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61873/6510).)
- Label the first frame with the optional argument `[label=first]`.

So, by doing either of the last three bullets, I can work around this problem and still retain the overlay behavior that I want.  Nevertheless, I would like to understand why this error arises.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There is also bug report at bitbucket:

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/204

---

The problem is that every cell is a single group and you can use `\onslide` for one row. The ampersand bust be separated. The documentation of `beamer` has an extra section about slides and tabular. So the way to do is:

```
  \onslide<1->{Some} & \onslide<1->{text} \
```

Here the complete mwe:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \includeonlyframes{second}

  \begin{frame}{First frame}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
      \onslide<1->{Some} & \onslide<1->{text} \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[label=second]{Second frame}
    Some text on second frame
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But what is really surprising is that `\onslide<+->{Some & text}` works fine as long as `\includeonlyframes{second}` is _not_ included!  Do you have any idea why this would be the case?  (The bug report that you linked to does not mention `\includeonlyframes` as far as I can see.)