# How to animate some part of texts?

Tags: beamer, animations, animate

I have two bullets in LaTeX as follow.

- Objective: Maximize f(x).
- Constraint: f(x)>0.

I would like to do some animations as follow.

First I would like to have:

- Objective:
- Constraint:

When I click on mouse or the keyboard for first time, I would like to show:

- Objective: Maximize f(x).
- Constraint:

Then, when I click for the second time, I would like to show:

- Objective: Maximize f(x).
- Constraint: f(x)>0.

Comment: Adding a minimum working example will encourage people to work on your code. As it is, anyone will have to create a document from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility. use of `\onlide<x->` or `\visible<x->` which means start from frame x and thereafter.

More information on[Differences and best practices: \onslide vs. \uncover, \onslide+ vs. \visible, \onslide* vs. \only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61873/34618)

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\bullet$] Optimization: \onslide<2->{Maximize $f(x)$}
\item[$\bullet$] Constaint:      \onslide<3->{$g(x)>0$}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```